# Error 401 when tweets using node-twitter

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, node-twitter

I am using Twitter API by the package [Twitter for Node.js](https://github.com/desmondmorris/node-twitter).

Right now I succeed reading tweets using stream, but I failed to write tweets. I got 401 error which means Unauthorized according to [Twitter Developer Documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes).

The code is here:

```
const Twitter = require('twitter');

const twitterClient = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: TwitterConsumerKey,
  consumer_secret: TwitterConsumerSecret,
  access_token_key: TwitterAccessTokenKey,
  access_token_secret: TwitterAccessTokenSecret
});

twitterClient.post('statuses/update', { status: 'Hello World!' },  (err, tweet, res) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(tweet);
  console.log(res);
});
```

I did give write access. What could be other reasons causing this? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work. Before I changed my access from "read" to "read, write, and direct messages". And I did regenerate my "consumer key and secret", also "access token and token secret" several times.

It should work, but it wasn't.

At last I totally delete the app on Twitter and recreated it, then it works!

Hope this can help people who met this weird issue.